# why do I get a "weakmethod" object error when using torch.save?

Tags: python, github, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to use the code from github repository: https://github.com/MIRACLE-Center/YOLO_Universal_Anatomical_Landmark_Detection and  I am having trouble with torch "weakmethod" object error. This code is not mine and I do not understand it completely. Can somebody help me please?

This is the link to pytorch bypass option: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/88684

I am using pytorch 2.0.1 where it was supposed to be resolved: https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/issues/15901

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jankovic/Downloads/Yolo_landmarks/universal_landmark_detection/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    Runner(args).run()
  File "/Users/jankovic/Downloads/Yolo_landmarks/universal_landmark_detection/model/runner.py", line 153, in run
    self.train()
  File "/Users/jankovic/Downloads/Yolo_landmarks/universal_landmark_detection/model/runner.py", line 286, in train
    torch.save(data, dest)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 441, in save
    _save(obj, opened_zipfile, pickle_module, pickle_protocol)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 653, in _save
    pickler.dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'WeakMethod' object
```